# How to calculate User reading Activity on current screen in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, time

I have one Task in my Application.

In Tableview I load the Some books list,
when a user selects the cell I open that book with PDF URL
I need to calculate how much time the user spends on that book for reading I need to send that time to the backend.

Suppose the user opens the book I will start the timer, how to I will observe either user read the book or suppose put in the background.

Any idea how to we caliculate that time

Answer (score 1):

In your `viewDidLoad()`. you can add an observer like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillResignActive(notification:)), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: UIApplication.shared)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive(notification:)), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: UIApplication.shared)
```

And to check when the user enters the background you can simply create this two methods.

```
var start: CFAbsoluteTime!

//This method will run when user enters the background  
@objc func applicationWillResignActive(notification: NSNotification){
    start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    print("Background entered")
}

//This method will run when user returned to the application
@objc func didBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification){
    let backgroundTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start
    print(backgroundTime)
    print("Returned to the application")
}
```